# To get from N-th elements till the last elements in excel Using JXL Java

Tags: java, excel, jxl

```
String dt=s.getCell(0,row).getContents();
```

How should I change it so I would be reading it starting from the fourth row till the last row? My code currently reads all the row from the first column. Any method I can use?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for(int row = 3; row < s.getRows(); row++){
   String dt=s.getCell(0,row).getContents();
   ...
}
```

This will loop through all the rows, starting from the 4th one `int row = 3`, if you want to start from another row, just change the initial value of the `row` variable (keep in mind that rows indexing starts at 0), if you want to get all the cells of all the rows after the 4th one, you can do it like this:

```
for(int row = 3; row < s.getRows(); row++){
   Cell[] cells = s.getRow(row);
   for(Cell cell:cells){
      String dt= cell.getContents();
      ....
   }
}
```